# Jquery mobile take too time to navigate between pages

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my jQuery mobile application for android platform when i move from one page to another the page flickers and take time to show " the transition is too slow" i have set the data-transition of all anchors '' to none  and make some updates as following ,but the problem still ,what i should do to make the app faster ??

please help me....

Main.html

```
 <html>
 <head>  
 <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />  
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,     minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,
 height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CustomStyles.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
 <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div data-role="page"    id="Main" >
 <div data-role="header"   > </div>
 <div data-role="content">
 <a href="Profile.html"  data-transition="none"  data-role="button"  data-theme="none"                  data-shadow="false"  data-corners="false" ><img src="images/profile.png"   /></a><BR><BR>                       <BR><BR>
<font color="white"  size="6px"  >  Profile </font>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/disableTransition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Main.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the following to my css file "CustomStyles.css" :

```
.ui-page {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;              

 }

.in, .out {
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 250ms !important;
  }

* {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   }
```

**disableTransition.js**   // it seems not working since i have added an alert to check if its work or not , but the alert didn't appear

```
document.addEventListener('mobileinit', MobileInit, false);


function MobileInit()
{
   alert('IN Mobile INIT Func');
   $.extend(  $.mobile , { defaultPageTransition: 'none' });
   $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
   $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
   $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement fastclick.js found here: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.

Link the .js to your document.

Simply add

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

to the head of my document.

No more flash/flicker when navigating between pages.

Comment: thank you for helping me since i am still suffering from this problem , i tried what you said , but the flicker still happen when i move from the home page to a page contains large list view  how can i solve this please ? any suggestions??

Comment: Make sure to initialize the script in you head tag and the script above. You can also try to add the script above to your <body> tag right before closing it </body>